# Why isn't delivery_mode boolean in RabbitMQ / AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Reading RabbitMQ tutorials I [stumbled](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) upon this sentence:

> delivery_mode: Marks a message as persistent (with a value of 2) or transient (any other value).

Why wasn't it made boolean if it has only two possible values? Did it have some other values previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, [AMQP 0.9.1 defines two values](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html):

> **octet** *delivery-mode* Non-persistent (1) or persistent (2).

RabbitMQ just interprets all values != 2 as equivalent to 1.

I do not know the historical reasons for choosing octet as the type.

Comment: I do not know for certain, but it's pretty common in low level protocols to leave a little "extra space" in case you want to extend the protocol later on. In this case, there isn't a huge difference between 1 bit and 1 byte, and the authors may have anticipated the need for other delivery modes, so they just used a whole byte to express the field.